# What's wrong with my c program concerned with linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

It is simply a function used in a c program concerned with linked list.
its function is pick out the m th number from a list like 1,2,3,4,5,...,n, and put it to the first place,normally,its former place will be deleted.
if my poor English doesn't explain my idea well,you may get it in the program.

Examples:

input:7 2

output:2 1 3 4 5 6 7

input:7 6

output:6 1 2 3 4 5 7

intput:7 8

output:1 2 3 4 5 6 7

and the problem now is that it doesn't run properly and even doesn't run at all when the former number is less than the latter one.It just appears an error.

```
  void movenode(SNODE *head, int m)
  {
    SNODE* t,* q;
    t=head;
    int len=0;
    while(t->next!=NULL)
    {
        t=t->next;
        len++;
    }
    //printf("%d",len);
    if(!(m>len||m==0||m==1))
    {
        while(t->next->num!=m)
            t=t->next;
        //printf("%d",t->next->num);
        q=t->next;
        t->next=q->next;
        free(q);
        SNODE * T;
        T = ( SNODE * ) malloc( sizeof( SNODE ) );
        T->next=head->next;
        head->next=T;
        T->num=m;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the actual behaviour differ from the desired behaviour? Is there an error message?

Comment: One obvious problem is that your function starts off by advancing `t` until `t->next == NULL`, then the `if` condition reads `t->next->num` which is therefore dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: You should be checking for `NULL` everywhere that it is possible for `NULL` to happen (e.g. after `t=t->next` in the `while` loop, and the result of malloc)

Comment: You code somehow assumes that the `num` for each node is equal to its position. That will make a boring list and also won't be true after moving the node.

Comment: Your code does not *"pick out the m th number from a list"*, it picks out the item with a data value of `m` - so why are values 0, 1 and `len` rejected? And why do you allocate memory for another node when you already have one? Lastly, you didn't reset `t=head` after counting the items in the list.

Comment: I've edited my question.Thanks for telling me what I should improve.If there still exist any problems,I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code:

- You want to traverse the list twice, but don't reset the iterating pointer after the first pass. This means that you will end up dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.
- You should make up your mind whether `m` denotes a position or a value. Your code somehow uses both definitions, which is incongruent.
- You are neither creating a new node nor are you deleting an old one. You just reposition an existing node within the same list. (You could delete the old node and create a new node with the same `num` at the front of the list, but updating the pointers may be more efficient.)
- You change the list's head, but the calling code will not know about the change, because your updates of the `head` in `movenode` are lost when you return from the function. You should either return the new head or pass the head by reference or write a wrapper struct around your list which you pass as reference.

When you think about your problem, you don't need the double loops, either. As you iterate through the list, keep track of the position and reorder the pointers when your condition is fulfilled. If you cannot satisfy your condition, `m` is out of range and you dont do anything.

Here's an example implementation:

```
/*
 *      Move the m-th node in the list to the front. The index 0
 *      refers to the list's head. Returns 1 if a node was moved or
 *      0 otherwise.
 */
int movenode(SNODE **head, int m)
{
    SNODE **t = head;

    if (m < 1) return 0;            /* nothing to do! */

    while ((*t)->next != NULL) {
        if (m == 1) {
            SNODE *p;

            /* extract node */
            p = (*t)->next;
            (*t)->next = p->next;

            /* insert at front */
            p->next = *head;
            *head = p;

            return 1;
        }

        t = &(*t)->next;
        m--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You call it like this:

```
movenode(&head, 1);           /* swap first two nodes */
```

Things to note:

- The `head` is passed as pointer to pointer, i.e. by reference. After you return, `head` will hold the new head, so that the calling code sees the updated list.
- The iterator `t` is also a pointer to a pointer. This is so the node extraction works: Your list is singly linked and doesn't have a pointer to the previous node. By keeping the address of the pointer that points to this node in the list (which will initially be the `head`) and by looking at the next node, you can update that pointer when you extract the node.
- Because you are looking at the next node when iterating, the condition is `m == 1`, not `m == 0`. `m` is decreased during iteration. You could alternatively keep an increasing count (as you have done with `len`) and compare it to `m`.
- The function returns 1 or 0, denoting whether a node was moved or not.

Comment: Thanks for your generous help.Your first advice solved my problem,while I still appreciate the other advice,which can form me into a good programming habit.Thanks.//if there are any grammar faults in my sentences,just forget it.